# Missing \endcsname inserted, Runaway Argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I have no idea what is going wrong here:
The error arose all of a sudden!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                   },


    }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \\
B1 \& B2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem are the empty lines in your `\tikzset` macro. The following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
        },
    }
}


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \\
B1 \& B2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm...thx..why does this happen? I mean a blank line shouldn't be a problem actually!?!

Comment: @Diger they are. In many macros (those which aren't long), empty lines are forbidden. This is due to the fact that empty lines are the same as `\par` and short macros can't contain a `\par`. You can comment out the empty lines with a leading `%` if you want the visual effect in your source files, though. `%` does comment out everything in the same row after it (including the newline) and all leading spaces in the next line.

Comment: Thx. Another question regarding tikzset: How do I color all cell/nodes in gray? I tried: rows /. style={nodes={fill=gray!10, text=black}} but it doesnt work... Also I can not add fill=!gray!10 in the nodes above (where rectangle, draw=black.... is in)

Comment: @Diger if it's another question, you might open another question.